# Unable to install stackengine package

Tags: packages, miktex2.9, stackengine

When I am running the `stackengine` package in LaTeX, I am getting an error:

`File listofitems.sty not found.`

I am trying to get this file through MiKTeX 2.9 package manager but I am not able to find any file of this name. My system is Windows 8.1 .  How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a recent package, maybe, you should synchronize repository (menu `Repository` in MiKTeX Package Repository).

Other than that, you can filter the list of packages in M.P.M. with the`Name` window in the tool bar. You can use only part of the package name if you're not sure of the exact name, like this:

[image]

Comment: I did this but I'm only getting `listofsymbols` and `listofanswers` in search results.

Comment: Did you synchronise the repository first?